# W3schools toggle switch does not work on IOS

Tags: ios, html, css

I'm following this w3schools.com tutorial to create a toggle switch...

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

But for some reason its very hard to press and doesn't work properly on IOS. Any ideas? I tried doing some googleing on it, but I couldn't find anything on it.

Here is the code...

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {display:none;}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work properly"?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot and how did you code it.

Comment: If you google for "checkbox hack" you'll find lots of resources.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing this...

```
<div id="SwitchDiv" onclick="if ($('#SwitchInput').attr('checked')) {$('#SwitchInput').attr('checked', false);} else {$('#SwitchInput').attr('checked', true);}">

               <label id="Switch" class="switch" style="pointer-events: none;">
                 <input style="pointer-events: none;" id="SwitchInput" onchange="ClickAlertsCheckbox(this)" type="checkbox" checked>
                 <span style="pointer-events: none;" class="slider round"></span>
               </label>

</div>
```